# Use variable of type Type as type

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

Lets assume I have these classes

```
Animal
Cat : Animal
Dog : Animal
```

If in a method somewhere I had the following:

```
Type animalType = someClass.Animal.GetType();
```

How can I cast `someClass.Animal` into whatever type is contained within `animalType`? Something like:

```
var animal = (animalType.Type)someClass.Animal;
```

Comment: What are you really trying to do? There shouldn't be any need to do this since you wouldn't be able to use its methods/properties anyway

Comment: I've been thinking about that issue over and over... I still thought it might be an interesting exercise.

Comment: It sounds like you really want an interface or just stronger inheritance

Answer (score 1):

You need a generic method for this:

```
public static class Converter
{
    public static T ConvertTo<T>(this object source) where T :class 
    {
        if (source is T)
        {
            return (T) source;
        }
        else
        {
            return null; // or throw exception
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use Reflection to call this method:

```
class Animal { }
class Cat : Animal { }

class Dog : Animal
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "I'm a dog!";
    }

     public bool IsDog { get { return true; } }
}

Animal a = new Dog();

var methodInfo = typeof (Converter)
                .GetMethod("ConvertTo", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

var method = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(a.GetType());

var dog = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { a });

Console.WriteLine(dog.ToString());
```

In this case, it will write `I'm a dog` to console. but since the `Invoke` method returns an object you can't access the methods or properties of the `Dog`.In order to do that, you can use *dynamic* feature:

```
dynamic dog = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { a });

Console.WriteLine(dog.IsDog); // true
```

But then you lose the *type-safety*.

As a result, if you don't know the type that you want to cast at *compile-time* there is no way to do this directly using a type instance.

Comment: dynamic is what I used in the past... which is precisely the reason I opened the question, I got to a point in the code where I knew whatever was there had a specific property, but since the the Interface was generic, I couldn't cast the object to the specific generic type. +1 for the good explanation though :)